# Removing non-alphanumeric characters with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have much files like these(please see the screenshot):

```
30.230201521829.jpg         
Mens-Sunglasses_L.180022111040.jpg   
progressive-sunglasses.180041285287.jpg
Atmosphere.222314222509.jpg  
Womens-Sunglasses-L.180023271958.jpg  
DAILY ESSENTIALS.211919012115.jpg
aviator-l.Sunglasses.240202216759.jpg 
aviator-l.Sunglasses.women.240202218530.jpg
```

I want to raname them to the following:

```
230201521829.jpg          
180022111040.jpg
180041285287.jpg
222314222509.jpg
172254027299.jpg
211919012115.jpg
240202216759.jpg 
240202218530.jpg
```

230201521829 is a timestamp ,180022111040 is a timestamp,180041285287 is a timestamp, etc.
**Ensure that the final file name looks like "timestamp.jpg".**

But I am not able to write the script more.
**Sed(Bash)** command or **Python** can be used to do it?
Could you give me a example? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You looking to actually rename the files? Not just change how the names appear?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to actually rename the files with bash or python.

Comment: I need to ask now. What is the exact expectation? (Say file is `a1.b2.c3.jpg`)
Remove everything till first `.`? (becomes `b2.c3.jpg`)
Remove all non-numeric characters (excluding extension part)? (becomes `123.jpg`)
Keep only numeric characters after first `.`? (becomes `23.jpg`)
keep only numeric characters in the last part (as separated by `.`) of the filename (excluding extension)? (becomes `3.jpg`)

Comment: 230201521829  is a timestamp ,180022111040 is a timestamp,180041285287 is a timestamp, etc.
Ensure that the final file name looks like "timestamp.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using command substitution for renaming the file. Following code will loop to the current directory's (unless path is modified) jpg files.

Awk is used to filter out the penultimate and last column of file name which are separated by "." .

```
for file in *.jpg
  do

    mv "$file" $(echo "$file" |awk -F'.' '{print $(NF-1)"." $NF}')

done
```

Comment: This will break for file name like "a.b c.jpg", basically, any file with space after the first dot.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I use python

examp.

```
import os
import sys
import glob

pth = "C:\Users\Test"
dir_show = os.listdir(pth)

for list_file in dir_show:
    if list_file.endswith(".JPG"):
        (shrname, exts) = os.path.splitext(list_file)
        path = os.path.join(pth, list_file)
        newname=os.path.join(pth,shrname[shrname.find(".")+1:len(shrname)]+".JPG")
        os.rename(path,newname)
```

Comment: You are not correct.  
If the file name is "aviator-l.Sunglasses.women.240202218530.jpg",
it will get "Sunglasses.women.240202218530.jpg" with your script.

Comment: I check point you use loop again

aviator-l.(Point-1)Sunglasses.(Point-2)women.(point-3)240202218530.jpg

you run script three time.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl rename](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) one-liner:

```
$ touch 30.230201521829.jpg Mens-Sunglasses_L.180022111040.jpg progressive-sunglasses.180041285287.jpg Atmosphere.222314222509.jpg Womens-Sunglasses-L.180023271958.jpg Womens-Eyeglasses-R.172254027299.jpg

$ ls -1
30.230201521829.jpg
Atmosphere.222314222509.jpg
Mens-Sunglasses_L.180022111040.jpg
progressive-sunglasses.180041285287.jpg
Womens-Eyeglasses-R.172254027299.jpg
Womens-Sunglasses-L.180023271958.jpg

$ prename -v 's/^[^.]*\.//' *.*.jpg
30.230201521829.jpg renamed as 230201521829.jpg
Atmosphere.222314222509.jpg renamed as 222314222509.jpg
Mens-Sunglasses_L.180022111040.jpg renamed as 180022111040.jpg
progressive-sunglasses.180041285287.jpg renamed as 180041285287.jpg
Womens-Eyeglasses-R.172254027299.jpg renamed as 172254027299.jpg
Womens-Sunglasses-L.180023271958.jpg renamed as 180023271958.jpg
```

Comment: @anishsane: afraid we both felt the same way :), the image attached has a file name as @James Brown was mentioning `30.123123123m.jpg.`

Comment: Yes. What is the expected result for that name? `123123123m.jpg` or `123123123.jpg` or `30123123123.jpg`?

Comment: Not sure @anishsane, OP needs to clarify a bit more on that

Comment: Well, leaving the `m` in the name would be the wisest thing to do, otherwise there would be overwrites. I'm just a nitpicker 'cause I couldn't do it with Bash one-liner. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter expansion to strip off the extension, then
remove all but the last `.`-delimited field from the remaining name. After than, you can reapply the extension.

```
for f in *; do
    ext=${f##*.}
    base=${f%.$ext}
    mv -- "$f" "${base##*.}.$ext"
done
```

The first line sets `ext` to the string following the last `.`. The second line sets `base` to the string that precedes the last `.` (by removing the last `.` and whatever `$ext` was set to). The third line constructs a new file name by first removing everything up to, and including, the final `.` in `base`, then reapplying the extension to the result.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash/
echo "test: "
echo "" > 30.230201521829.jpg         
echo "" > Mens-Sunglasses_L.180022111040.jpg   
echo "" > progressive-sunglasses.180041285287.jpg
echo "" > Atmosphere.222314222509.jpg  
echo "" > Womens-Sunglasses-L.180023271958.jpg  
echo "" > DAILY\ ESSENTIALS.211919012115.jpg
echo "" > aviator-l.Sunglasses.240202216759.jpg 
echo "" > aviator-l.Sunglasses.women.240202218530.jpg 
echo "before: "
ls -ltr
for f in *.jpg; do
       renamed=${f: -16}
       mv "${f}" "${renamed}"
done
```

Comment: This would turn `30.230201521829.jpg` into `3023020152189.jpg`, rather than `230201521829.jpg`.

Comment: This will break , if any file name is having space in it.

Comment: Please try running your script before posting it. Hint: Current version will try to run `$f` as command.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.